# Change LinearLayout height by number of lines of textview in java

Tags: java, textview, height, line, android-linearlayout

I have a textview in a LinearLayout, and I want the height of LinearLayout to be changed from the number of lines in textview, please sombody will help me and tell me how can I do it without any problems?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. There is no illustration or examples

but I believe you can make the LinearLayout's height to be wrap
and the child's TextView to have lines="3" for example

by that your linearlayout will have a height of 3 lines as per the above example